# How to create query condition where comparing field is equal to a dynamic value in Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0, dynamic-queries

I'm trying to create a query like this:

```
$spreadsheet = $this->Spreadsheets->get($id, [
        'contain' => [
            'SpreadsheetTypes.CentersTypes' => function ($q) {
                return $q->matching('Centers', function ($q) {
                    return $q->where(['Centers.id' => 5]);
                })->contain(['Items']);
            }
        ]
    ]);
```

$id value is passed by parameter. But I need to change

```
return $q->where(['Centers.id' => 5])
```

because I need to compare 'Centers.id' with center_id value that I will get on this query. I mean, Spreadsheets has a center_id field, so, I need to compare with it.
Any idea?

Comment: While it's relatively easy to answer that question, once one understood what exactly you'are asking for, it's hard to tell whether that will actually work, as your association types, as well as the intent of that query are unknown. With the query that you're showing, such a comparison will for example only work if all containments are 1:1 or n:1 associations.

Comment: Additionally to the association details, it would also help if you mention why you're using the containments, ie do you actually want to contain that data, or do you only want to filter by these associations.

Answer (score 0):

add "use" after function ($q)

exemple

```
return $q->matching('Centers', function ($q) use($foo) {
                    return $q->where(['Centers.id' => $foo]);
                })->co
```

Comment: Hi!
It doesn't resolve my problem, because I want to compare with center_id of the spreadsheet that I will get... so, at this moment, I don't know the value

Comment: Did you try to pass $id in your contain too ?  like this

$spreadsheet = $this->Spreadsheets->get($id, [
        'contain' => [
            'SpreadsheetTypes.CentersTypes' => function ($q) use($id) {
                return $q->matching('Centers', function ($q) use($id){
                    return $q->where(['Centers.id' => $id]);
                })->contain(['Items']);
            }
        ]
    ]);